# How can I apply a cursor style when dragging text?

Tags: javascript, css

Example:

[image: Text dragging cursor]

I don't want the "blocked" style of cursor when I drag the word.

Can I use CSS or JS to keep the `default` or `pointer` cursor style?

Comment: u cant do it but u could disable text selection highlighting,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: thanks your comment, maybe I without express clearly. I don't want the cursor become "Black disable cursor", I hope then cursor can keep default.